# Form button and css sprite image. spillage

Tags: html, css

I have these 3 buttons: Save, Apply, Cancel, I am using a Sprite images. 
See the attacked image. You will notice the correct image sprite is being display on the far left side of each button. 
Why is the rest of the sprite images spilling over? Anyone has any ideas?

```
#submit_save  {background-position: -131px -131px;}
#submit_apply {background-position: -207px -131px;}
#submit_cancel{background-position: -131px -165px;}
```

[image]

Comment: Your sprite image has a horizontal icons, try with using vertical icon with some space between them...

Comment: That worked too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the images into separate containers (divs) that you put into the buttons, and define height and width values for these to only make the relevant part of the sprite visible. height and width of these container divs depend on the part of the sprite you want to display (together with `background-position`)

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I can't do this with pure CSS. Might do away with the Sprite and use a single image. I know that this way it will work with just CSS